# Misma subcategorias para todas las categorias padres

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Saludos se que es una cosa de locos, pero tengo curiosidad de saber si es posible usar las mismas subcategorias para varias categorías padres **sin necesidad de crearlas para cada cual.** EJEMPLO:

```
Subcategoria 1
Subcategoria 2
Subcategoria 3
Subcategoria 4
Subcategoria 5
```

Sean las mismas para

```
Categoria Padre 1
Categoria Padre 2
Categoria Padre 3
```

Y así sucesivamente

Answer (score 0):

Las mismas exactamente, no. Porque cada categoría (sea descendiente de otra o no), tiene su propio ID, y no pueden tener más de un ancestro.

Puedes emular una estructura así pero sólo con títulos. Es decir sólo los nombres serían iguales, pero en realidad solo estás replicando la idea.

Comment: Si eso me temía, otra idea para ahorrar tiempo puede ser crear un lote sql y asignárselo a la categoría padre mediante el id cierto?

Comment: Un lote? No entiendo. Te refieres a registros en la tabla que a mano los asignes a otro registro como parent?

Comment: Si crear una query para insertar datos a la base de datos, con todos las subcategorias y solo cambiar los ids de la categoría padre en cada query.

Comment: Te recomendaría mejor usar "WordPress como si fuera WordPress" y no cualquier demo que sólo tienes SQL para trabajar. Hay actions y funciones que puedes usar para disparar todas las consultas requeridas para crear las categorías descendientes, te va a ahorrar mucho tiempo.